# How does Timmy get fairies in Fairly OddParents?

Tags: the-fairly-oddparents

I want to make a Bible version story book of Fairly OddParents, but I need to know how Timmy got his fairies because I move on from there. Thanks and God bless you all.

Comment: I cannot fathom what a bible version story book of Fairly OddParents is.

Answer (score 2):

Timmy is shown receiving his fairies in the pilot episode, at about 2:20 in the video below. It aired as a segment of *Oh Yeah! Cartoons*.

The two key factors in his receiving godparents are the abuse he receives from his babysitter Vicky, and the neglect he suffers from his parents (chiefly, them constantly leaving him in Vicky's care in the first place). The pilot depicts this quite plainly, and after enduring hours of abuse from Vicky, Timmy hurls his Magic 9-Ball at the wall in frustration. The 9-Ball splits in half to reveal Cosmo and Wanda, who announce themselves as his fairy godparents.

Answer (score 1):

My vague recollection is that Timmy was assigned fairies because his parents ignored or neglected him, and he was the victim of bullying from multiple sources. There is a fairy world that works like a big corporation, which I guess you can think of similar to child protective services if you will. They monitor children of earth and grant fairies to those children in need of them.